# prove the following: using a similar proof as Bolzano's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : [0, 1] → R$ be continuous with $f (0) = f (1) = 0$. Further suppose that whenever $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ for some $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$ there exists at least one $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f (c) = 0$. Show that $f (x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

I have this to prove but I'm not sure with what idea to start this proof.

Comment: The main ingredient of Bolzano's theorem is this dichotomy, where you split each interval in two iteratively to focus on it. This is the core idea that you should use here, combine with a contradiction proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $f(1)=f(0)=0$ and by the property of the function given in the question, then $\exists^{\geq 1} c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=0$.

Define the sets as follow:

$$A:=\{x \in [0,c) | f(x)=0\} \;\; B:=\{x\in (c,1] | f(x)=0\} $$

Since we have $f(0)=0$, then we know $A \neq \emptyset$. Similarly we know $B \neq \emptyset$.

Note that the intervals $[0,c)$ and $(c,1]$ are bounded (above by $c$ and below by $c$ respectively.
Therefore we know that $A$ is bounded above, and $B$ is bounded below. Thus $\exists \sup{A}, \inf{B}$.

Particularly, we have $0 \leq \sup{A} \leq c \leq \inf{B} \leq 1$.

Since $c \in (0,1)$, we have $\sup{A}, \inf{B} \in [0.1]$ and so $f$ has a value for these inputs.

Now, by the approximation property of the supremum, that is: $\exists a \in A \;\text{such that}\;\sup{A}+\frac{1}{n} < a \leq \sup{A}$

Thus, we have:

$$\exists(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A \;\;\text{such that}\;\; x_n\rightarrow \sup{A}$$

By continuity, $f(\sup{A}) \rightarrow f(x_n)$. However, by definition of $A$, we have $f(x_n)=0 \;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $f(\sup{A})=0$.

We do the same procedure for finding $f(\inf{B})$ and then conclude that $f(x)=0 \; \forall x \in [0,1]$ via contradiction of the supremum/infimum properties.